# How to handle exception in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

my code:

```
try {
    LinkedDataForm form = webService.process(searchForm, path);
    add(new ExternalLink("url", form.getUrl(), form.getUrl()));

} catch (Exception e) {
    add(new Label("error", e.getMessage()));
}
```

where:

```
@SpringBean(name = "webService")
WebService webService;
```

and my html page looks like:

```
<a wicket:id="url">url</a>
<p wicket:id="error"/>
```

the problem is in html page that I have url or error and then wicket return exception:  `Unable to find component with id 'error' in ...`
how I can solve this problem

Comment: So if there's no exception, you won't add that label and it won't be found. Obviously that cannot work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ist that you only add the error label when you have an exception. The quick and dirty way would be to add a `EmptyPanel("error");` just at the last line in the try block.

A better way would be to use wickets FeedbackPanel and instead of adding an Label with the exception message to `error(e.getMessage());` in the catch block.

Answer (score -1):

Wicket has some powerful mechanism for handling exceptions (that are result of some serious failure) and errors (that are result of wrong user input).

I recommend to have a look at the [wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/error-pages-and-feedback-messages.html) or at some examples about [feedback messages in wicket](http://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=wicket%20feedback%20message).